# How to find the Server Name of MySQL

Tags: mysql, connection-string

Where can I find the name of MySQL which I'll use at the connection string to connect to the database from c#?

Comment: do u mean where is the server name or IP for the running mysql daemon/program ?

Comment: Yes, where can I find it written?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I also get an error when I try some URL saying "Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for us
er 'root'@'sfn-inkubator-70-61.hib.no' (using password: YES)"
Although it logs on smoothly through the myadmin portal. Any clues?

Comment: if in linux environment, you can consider `port number or socket`, hopefully windows similar to linux in this manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'sfn-inkubator-70-61.hib.no' (using password: YES)" error means that you have setup connection address correctly. Client connects to server, but server rejects username and password combination.

So you need to check your server setup, create some user with known password and so on......

Answer (score 10):

If you're connecting to a db on the same server, it should be "`localhost`".

If you are connecting to a remote server, then it should be the FQDN of the remote server (or the IP address) - for example, "`dbhost.lan.company.com`".

Comment: I get an error when I try some URL saying "Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for us er 'root'@'sfn-inkubator-70-61.hib.no' (using password: YES)" Although it logs on smoothly through the myadmin portal. Any clues?

Comment: @Ahmad Farid - what is the exact connect function/string you're trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible your host blocks external access to your mysql db, quite a few do.  This would explain why you can connect via myadmin.